# How to turn a list into a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Beginner programmer here. I have 2 questions.

1. Turn a list into a nested dictionary:

   house_prices = ['£200k', '£300k', '£500k'`]

I want to turn it into--

```
House_price_dict = {
'house1': {'price':'£200k'},
'house2': {'price':'£300k'},
'house3': {'price:'£500k'},
}
```

2. Turn two lists into a nested dictionary:

   house_prices = ['£200k', '£300k', '£500k'`]

   no_of_bedrooms = [2, 3, 5]

I want to turn into--

```
house_info_dict = {
    'house1': {
        'price':'£200k',
        'no_of_bedrooms':2,
        },
    'house2': {
        'price':'£300k',
        'no_of_bedrooms': 3,
        },
    'house3': {
        'price:'£500k',
        'no_of_bedrooms': 5,
        },
    }
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
d = {} 
for i in xrange(len(house_prices)):
    d["house{}".format(i+1)] = { "price": house_prices[i] }
```

For the second part:

```py
d = {} 
for i in xrange(len(house_prices)):
    d["house{}".format(i+1)] = { "price": house_prices[i], 'no_of_bedrooms': no_of_bedrooms[i] }
```

Note that `house_prices` and `no_of_bedrooms` must be in the same size, otherwise `IndexError` will be raised.

Comment: what does `xrange` means? did you meant to `range`?

Comment: `range` if you are using python 3, `xrange` if you are using python 2. Note that  `range` also exists in python 2, but is different from the one in python 3.

Answer (score 3):

The zip function takes multiple lists and returns tuples with one element from each list:

```
>>> house_prices = ['200k', '300k', '500k']
>>> no_of_bedrooms = [2, 3, 5]
>>>
>>> list(zip(house_prices, no_of_bedrooms))
[('200k', 2), ('300k', 3), ('500k', 5)]
>>>
```

zip returns a generator, so I convert it to list above to see the result.

There is a built-in enumerate function that returns both the index and the value in a list:

```
>>> for i, n in enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c'], start=1):
...     print(i, n)
...
1 a
2 b
3 c
>>>
```

combining the two, gives:

```
>>> list(enumerate(zip(house_prices, no_of_bedrooms), start=1))
[(1, ('200k', 2)), (2, ('300k', 3)), (3, ('500k', 5))]
```

and you can feed this into a dict comprehension:

```
>>> house_info_dict = {'house%d' % i: {
...     'price': p,
...     'no_of_bedrooms': n
... } for i, (p, n) in enumerate(zip(house_prices, no_of_bedrooms), start=1)}
>>> house_info_dict
{'house3': {'no_of_bedrooms': 5, 'price': '500k'}, 'house2': {'no_of_bedrooms': 3, 'price': '300k'}, 'house1': {'no_of_bedrooms': 2, 'price': '200k'}}
```

a trick to print it in a prettier format is to use the json module:

```
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps(house_info_dict, indent=4))
{
    "house3": {
        "no_of_bedrooms": 5,
        "price": "500k"
    },
    "house2": {
        "no_of_bedrooms": 3,
        "price": "300k"
    },
    "house1": {
        "no_of_bedrooms": 2,
        "price": "200k"
    }
}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use dictionany comprehension

```
house_prices = ['£200k', '£300k', '£500k']
House_price_dict = {f'house{idx}':{'price':i} for idx, i in enumerate(house_prices, start=1)}

#{'house1': {'price': '£200k'},
# 'house2': {'price': '£300k'},
# 'house3': {'price': '£500k'}}

no_of_bedrooms = [2, 3, 5]
house_info_dict = {f'house{idx}':{'price':i[0], 'no_of_bedrooms': i[1]} for idx, i in enumerate(zip(house_prices, no_of_bedrooms), start=1)}

#{'house1': {'price': '£200k', 'no_of_bedrooms': 2},
# 'house2': {'price': '£300k', 'no_of_bedrooms': 3},
# 'house3': {'price': '£500k', 'no_of_bedrooms': 5}}
```